# electronic component (perhaps an op amp) identification

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, identification, components

I was looking through some components I got in a kit a few years ago, and I found what I think is an op-amp. Unfortunately, any documentation for the kit is long gone. (Although I don't think it was particularly useful to begin with) I would like to identify the component, but I can't seem to find any documentation online from the numbers on the chip. The logo loos like a "yw" but I can't find that anywhere either.

I got this part from a "Minitronics Survival Guts with 60+ components" package that was in a "Make: Raspberry Pi Starter Kit" from radioshack.

The text on the chip, as far as I can make out, reads:

UTC358D
(The Logo) P3M6DC

on the bottom of the chip, there is the code "J20" centered in a small circle.

Any Help is appreciated!
Thank You!

[image]
[image]

Comment: ALmost certainly an LM358 dual op amp, with a UTC part no.

Comment: Have you tried googling the part number? https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/774671/UTC/UTC358/1

Comment: I did, but I guess I did a bad job of it... Thanks for finding that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hello it seems to be a [dual operational amplifier IC](https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile-pdf/774671/UTC/UTC358/1)

i hope this helps

Comment: +1 Specifically, a clone of the National Semiconductor (now TI) LM358 made in China by Hangzhou Youwang Electronics.